# Using wildcard to run multiple scripts for npm run test

Tags: javascript, npm

I my package.json I have

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node tests/*-test.js"
}
```

And I have `a-test.js` and `b-test.js` in the `tests` folder, which I can verify by running `ls tests/*-test.js`.

However, `npm run test` is only executing `a-test.js`. How can I execute all `*-test.js` scripts? Explicitly listing them is not an option, since I will have more than 2 to run in the future.

Comment: have you tried this node tests/*-test.js command in shell?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a task manager such as `grunt` or `gulp`, or a simple script that execute those scripts:

test.js:

```
require('./test/a-test.js')
require('./test/b-test.js')
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "node test.js"
}
```

You could also use the include-all module for automating these for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/include-all

Example using includeAll:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const includeAll = require('include-all');

    const controller = includeAll({
        dirname: path.join(__dirname, 'test'),
        filter: /(.+test)\.js$/,
    });
```

Comment: Running that test.js doesn't work: `Error: Cannot find module 'a-test.js'` Is there another step I need to take? I put them all in the `test` folder and removed the "test/" from the requires.

I also made the includeAll script and it doesn't run anything! I want this all to go under the test folder, if that matters.

Comment: sorry it is `require('./test/a-test.js')`, updating

Comment: It seem to be suppressing the output from one of my tests that uses API-easy.js. If I run the test on it's own, I get a list of checkmarks and failures. But using your test.js answer, It prints out console.log statements, but nothing else. Any idea why?

Comment: what else it is suppose to log? could you post an example of your test files

Comment: you could also encapsulate your test files in a function so you can call them instead, `Object.keys(controller).forEach(key => controller[key]());`, it should solve your api-easy problem

Comment: `console.log("testing"); suite.use('localhost').discuss('asdf,').post('/login', { username: name, password: pass}).expect(200, { username: name }).undiscuss()`

If I run that test alone, it'll output whether it passed or not. But if I run it as part of the `test.js` solution, it'll just print "testing" and nothing else, then run the other test file.